# Error when Querying/Selecting excel column

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I followed tutorial in here: http://codehill.com/2009/01/reading-excel-2003-and-2007-files-using-oledb/

but i want only view some columns ,so i edit the query into

```
"select F1,F3,F6 from [" + worksheetName + "$]", con);
```

but i got this error on line

```
cmd.Fill(excelDataSet);


System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled
  Message=No value given for one or more required parameters.
  Source=Microsoft Access Database Engine
  ErrorCode=-2147217904
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
       at ExcelReader.mainForm.GetWorksheet(String worksheetName) in D:\PLN\ExcelReader\ExcelReader\Main.cs:line 112
       at ExcelReader.mainForm.sheetsToolStripComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\PLN\ExcelReader\ExcelReader\Main.cs:line 125
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_SelectedIndex(Int32 value)
       at ExcelReader.mainForm.openToolStripButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\PLN\ExcelReader\ExcelReader\Main.cs:line 51
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at ExcelReader.Program.Main() in D:\PLN\ExcelReader\ExcelReader\Program.cs:line 17
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The dummy field names `F1`, `F2` and so on are only used if a column has no value in the header row or if the connection string contains `HDR=No`

If you have values in the header row and you have `HDR=Yes` in the connection string then you need to use the actual column titles and not the dummy field names like `F1`